# .Find is not looking in values

Tags: vba, excel

For some weird reason when cell B3 has a value "48987" and it is formatted as general (number, not string because it is right aligned) the `find` function works but when it is formatted as a comma separated number, the `find` function is unable to find it. The code given below is what I'm trying.

```
Set Loc = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10").Find("48987", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not (Loc Is Nothing) Then
   Debug.Print Loc.Address
End If
```

**Note:** I've tried with/without double quotes and the lookin options

But the moment I change the code to the one given below it works!!

```
Set Loc = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10").Find("48,987", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I've restarted my system and done a lot of search but I'm unable to find a solution. This happens with dates because they are stored as an integer in excel but I don't know why this would happen with a number. Plus the same cell does get detected when I change the condition

Comment: Have you tried `Set Loc = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10").Find(48987, LookIn:=xlformulas)`? It's usually a good idea to specify more of the parameters such as searchformat.

Comment: What happens when you select the `48987` and you write `?selection` in the immediate window?

Comment: @Vityata it gives 48987

Comment: @SJR I thought I had tried that but xlformulas does work!
I wonder why though

Comment: That is strange. What happens if you open a new excel file and manually write 48987 and try to get it through find?

Comment: @Vityata That is exactly what I had done. I had a code written by me which was not working so to figure it out I checked every segment in a new excel file. After finding the problem I simplified it and posted it on stackoverflow

Comment: I think Formulas ignores formatting (so if comparing with the properties of a range is more comparable to `Value`) whereas Values does not (so is actually more comparable to the `Text` property). Have to say that when I just googled this, there is surprisingly little clear guidance. The lesson seems to be that Formulas is preferable in most cases as it searches contents and formulas.

Comment: @SJR Exactly even I kind of knew what the problem was, but I couldn't find much online. Thanks a lot for your help! and I think you should post that as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked ...

When using the `Find` method and its `LookIn` parameter, `xlFormulas` ignores formatting (so if comparing with a range is more comparable to the `Value` property) whereas `xlValues` does not (so is actually more comparable to the `Text` property). Therefore, in most cases `xlFormulas` is preferable as it searches contents and formulas.

It's also good practice to specify other `Find` parameters as they can be inadvertently changed (via the worksheet) and may not be set to the values you expect.