# Find method not finding result

Tags: excel, vba, find

I've a Find line that will not find  any result.

```vb
Sub Marketable()
    Dim SKU As String
    Dim Desc As String
    Dim Answer As String
    Dim Cnt As Integer
    Dim MktCol As Long
    Dim Mkt As Range
    Dim MktRng As Range
    Dim EAOCol As Long
    Dim EAO As Range
    Dim FirstMatch As Variant
    
    'This goes through each item in the dashboard that doesn't have the marketable field filled out, and asks the user to answer it
    'Check for proper file
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    If InStr(FileName, "Leadership Dashboard") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Wrong type of file for this Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Remove all the #N/As since they crash my code
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(1, 2).EntireColumn.Replace What:="#N/A", replacement:="-"
    Cells(1, 3).EntireColumn.Replace What:="#N/A", replacement:="-"
    Cells(1, 4).EntireColumn.Replace What:="#N/A", replacement:="-"
    With Range(Cells(4, 6), Cells(lr, 6))
        .Replace What:="#N/A", replacement:="-"
        .Replace What:="", replacement:="-"
    End With
    
    'Loop through and count how many are not marketable and give me a warning
    i = 4
    'Identify the marketable and E&O columns
    MktCol = Rows(3).Find(What:="Mkt", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    EAOCol = Rows(3).Find(What:="6M EO QTY", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    'Set the range of the marketable column
    Set MktRng = Range(Cells(i, MktCol), Cells(lr, MktCol))
    'Find the first example of an unmarked cell in the marketable column
    Set Mkt = MktRng.Find(What:="-", After:=Cells(lr, MktCol), _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Cells(Mkt.Row, EAOCol) > 0 Then 'If the first instance I found doesn't have any E&O, we're done here
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        FirstMatch = Mkt.Address 'Set the address of the first one I found, so once it loops back, it knows it's made a full orbit
    Else
        MsgBox "You don't have any unmarked E&O"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do
        Set Mkt = MktRng.FindNext(Mkt) 'Find the next one, and the next one, and the next one...
        If Cells(Mkt.Row, EAOCol) > 0 Then
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        If Mkt.Address = FirstMatch Then Exit Do 'If by some miracle, not one unmarked one has a zero E&O value, this will exit at the end
    Loop
    
    'Check if I want to proceed after finding how many there are
    Answer = MsgBox("You really want to go through this whole marketable thing, dude? We could be here a while. There's like " & Cnt & " of these things!", vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    'Now, look through all the ones missing that info
    Do
        Set Mkt = MktRng.Find(What:="-", After:=Cells(lr, MktCol), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        SKU = Cells(Mkt.Row, 1)
        Desc = Cells(Mkt.Row, 5)
        If Cells(Mkt.Row, EAOCol) > 0 Then
            Rows(Mkt.Row).Select
            Answer = MsgBox(Desc, vbYesNoCancel, SKU & " - " & Cnt)
            Cnt = Cnt - 1
            Select Case Answer
                Case Is = vbYes
                    Mkt = "y"
                Case Is = vbNo
                    Mkt = "n"
                Case Is = vbCancel
                   Exit Do
            End Select
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set Mkt = MktRng.FindNext(Mkt)
        If Cells(Mkt.Row, EAOCol) < 1 Then Exit Do
        If Mkt.Address = FirstMatch Then Exit Do
    
    Loop
End Sub
```

MktRng is column F, but only from row 4 to the last used cell (lr).
MktCol is Column F, found by looking for the header.

In cells F6, F12, and more, there are simple dashes, which is what it's searching for.
I tried changing the search to the word "Test" and making one of the cells value equal to "Test" and it finds nothing.

This worked previously in testing.

Comment: Is there a dash, or a `0` that's formatted to look like a dash?

Comment: It's definitely a dash. It was put there by replacing blanks with a dash earlier in the code. But also, I did try a test value that was different, and it also didn't find it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM24W.png

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it will loop back. Can't repro either.

Comment: This is pretty odd, then. As I mentioned, it worked previously, and now you can't reproduce. I'm flummoxed. I start at the last row, because it also has a find next feature, so I want it to start at the end first, then go back to the beginning and loop around to the end again.

Comment: I've updated to add the whole macro. I'd even be happy to send the Workbook to test on if that helped.

Comment: Aren’t there about 3 or 4 different "dashes"? Em-dash etc

Comment: You can share a workbook from google drive, etc.  Keep any code in that file to a minimum though - typically folks here won't download macro-enabled files, or if they do they don't want to review a ton of irrelevant code before enabling macros in that file.  Ideally if your posted code is complete you could just upload the data as xlsx.

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah, but earlier in the code, you can see I assign the dash to blanks and #N/A, then going to find the dash from there. So it's the same dash.

Comment: @TimWilliams Here's the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/154iMbFOWzv-7JYWScJD0e0XTE_pM763J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have a custom numberformat applied to ColF - if you switch that to "General" then it works fine with `LookIn:=xlValues`   See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929770/478884

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this question in a Udemy course I've purchased, and someone there advised that I needed to make my lookin:xlFormulas. I'm not sure why this is the case, since it's just a dash, and that wouldn't explain why when I tried searching for "test" it also didn't work. But making that change did seem to correct it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929770/478884